# Highlighting or selecting all values from Legend

Tags: legend, vega-lite

Why when hovering over the bottom "legend" every time only one of the entries or the last one is highlighted. Is there a way to highlight or even better select all components which have same color ? [Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-aTmcnRdrIV3SL2f8SxE-Ravmy-o9aUCiiVw58FX5oypEfG1aitRj0HqDbijQSs428wWW9Tg6XGehrDNq7aZm2ub63rnPgHRdvvSGu0Cm73mgPGtf1Zr0TqJ2mpxnCXuc3KFx7W6eTgBdU4QEwNokFkCAADM2DaBAjFACCaEEa02jQeCaDgQQLgXJRQNkMgtmMEAAE84A1NBASUBA5HoapAjqClUEKR0SLI0ojko6iYFosh6OtNALE8Y5AMdMg2jYBgcCYIijAHf8lAAdxoWRlDYeS4JANgcHMKBxNkTB7AQjCLmdJQkAMdAdIYPTOmdISWmg-TUEIwzMPMMwhMdKAdCgBhBAYlQ1AYBBKEs6zTHcABqdwAHIAA9UBiyL3FUTAgsMaLlGi-9bnMkBRPEnAlJ4uy1RwJAoCKtAxCUYgdNkLzHMIxTlBo8FoiUOB6rYZRKs0YjUJAFyLiqJRMCInAdWgnrZB0ewekwQQtlkXzBFM2KaHM0A-KYDCAGE2EEaDzCYPyoAAa3pY4gL8kiUKc0AytAhBzMImaxwwGgyBgYQvv0loMMmRzQDGibzBwNglL+jT5HQKiGAgOA2FIFCrrLN7JsKnSEC0-7FqgIHgPGnVwchgz0Mwl7ZKApglIuRb8OU+k5JAZA2guvqQZ1JgyJRMSzq506LqAzqdOmni+tigahvMFBRqJ8xrWx6DZrWjaBu2jCAFFYpwO6AtS4KNcEewjf2w69ZO8qLqUUTnVQEC9BttpTA2CAuKciQxGZ23lDNo70FEuBpKUAAvWm4El1ALCUaD0L0462GwNhYKUKCYLUcwAFIAAlUEzxI84GelRroRbzGSbUCDGBhQJ6ORi5AWL4T66X0HSICdPNga6p6uuYcI61WjcwLguUdwAF5x5ippovsbRdB1NpXGL4H9Ec-WgsoMfJ+nqxZ5qnQ9GOheV+Atfh4NreJ6n6K433kB56PgOl86pmlHpzr6mWwRBCA1o+bgE4UwrVQA9zoOwfuD0NRIFgugGAn1voIKhogHAY00AQR0AjA+J8o4lUflsQSMcyoVTQX1MBfd1KDwJq3EAnROgIzxtaZQdD7BwAAI4MFmugNgEEIIN3wWgTwlAxCOkejA8wmkaBYxxg-Q+WwLB4LkYI4RQFMBsAOj0LS91BrkwuLLYCpcnyojmvLdAitwagWNqnaCyB16Z2UPwTOTBHFEXcDnPOiRT40PSCXBaOpNaMzlqDMxKDlZWMGjYjO6B7GOOcZnVx7j85M1RqAVm7NgamJACTeOvM2D8wVrhCAj1Or6WFl1MWA1I5oSMuYbChNglnyVpYuahi0Df1Wg4dam0QCmwOv7L4gt7A+zQA7OATsXZmXdoYT2zMw7KQjvxGOzsSkK00gZSJdiHFOJcSbJAO1BDa11uYGA4k2gQAABQpTStFfBWUACU18vDuAAPzJRHulI2WV3AJWirPK6V1AJlmaq1UYnglBiOeupdGxyEE-SwPYBhgMBqczBhDHJ0NzBwwRkjOAKMSppORZkpe+NoTQVkLigASkgHq8M0A2AUsA92FhqoYDgEg-iIiOrlN6qAKpOianPwKpVIJk02jTRVp0tWfUjYAAVqUVNQPwQoSy47ryYInNRKcDF+LaStd+eyMJ+DwmXKIMZk5ICUugzBYyDHnXMhgwQWCekGsEAAGV6HQKqhC1QOSlroty9gpq4pltAT+lVUbyj6XdUBche4QMoefdAVzR6PNvhYe+Aj0BL3cmWKhF9N7bxvkiDNSi24n0dHmpNI8r471vjYEtOC8ov3kIoxt8l4F8T-iBPJgDGXd1jeA+u2iIUwq+nC5B2NSEOqdZmhRzNM2CQBZUOQCFxagCQF05Fhi-YW0GUBYg6E1J9X-j2gpYEikahWf8oAA)

Comment: Did the solution below solve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I also added some opacity in case that was interesting.
Remember to mark as closed if this solves your issue.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A1",
        "d": "B1",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "124",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 10:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 18:02:31 GMT",
        "c": "A2",
        "d": "B2",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 14:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "125",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 19:01:07 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 22:01:17 GMT",
        "c": "A1",
        "d": "B2",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 22:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "126",
        "a": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A4",
        "d": "B3",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 07 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "127",
        "a": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A4",
        "d": "B3",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      },
      {
        "id": "128",
        "a": "Wed, 08 Aug 2023 06:00:00 GMT",
        "b": "Wed, 08 Aug 2023 17:00:23 GMT",
        "c": "A1",
        "d": "B1",
        "start_time": "Sat, 30 Dec 1899 06:00:00 GMT",
        "Date": "Wed, 09 Aug 2023"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "Date",
        "range": [
          {"year": 2023, "month": "Aug", "date": 7},
          {"year": 2023, "month": "Aug", "date": 10}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "groupby": ["d"],
      "window": [{"op": "count", "field": "id", "as": "count_id"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "d"}]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.count_id + 'x: ' + datum['d']", "as": "grouping"}
  ],
  "spacing": 10,
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "width": 300,
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "c",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "title": null,
          "axis": {"labelColor": "black"}
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "highlight",
              "select": {"type": "point", "on": "mouseover"}
            }
          ],
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "stroke": "#5F5F5F", "cornerRadius": 4},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "a",
              "type": "temporal",
              "axis": {
                "labelExpr": "datum.label",
                "labelColor": "black",
                "grid": true,
                "gridDash": [5.5],
                "gridColor": "grey",
                "zindex": 1,
                "orient": "bottom",
                "format": "%H:%M:%S"
              },
              "title": "Time/Duration"
            },
            "x2": {"field": "b"},
            "color": {
              "condition": [
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B1'", "value": "#F95F3E"},
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B2'", "value": "#308DDC"},
                {"test": "datum.d == 'B3'", "value": "#2BC121"}
              ],
              "legend": null
            },
            "strokeWidth": {
              "condition": [
                {"param": "user_selected", "empty": false, "value": 1}
              ],
              "value": 0
            },
            "opacity": {
              "condition": {"selection": "user_selected", "value": 1},
              "value": 0.2
            },
            "tooltip": [
              {
                "field": "a",
                "title": "Start",
                "type": "temporal",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y %H:%M"
              },
              {
                "field": "b",
                "title": "End",
                "type": "temporal",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y %H:%M"
              },
              {"field": "d", "title": "D", "type": "nominal"}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "point", "stroke": "transparent"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Date",
              "type": "temporal",
              "title": null,
              "axis": {
                "labelColor": "black",
                "grid": true,
                "gridDash": [5.5],
                "zindex": 1,
                "orient": "top",
                "format": "%d-%b-%y",
                "labelExpr": "hours(datum['value']) == 0 ? datum['label'] : ''"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": 300,
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "user_selected",
          "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["d"]},
          "on": "click",
          "clear": "click"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "rect", "cornerRadius": 3, "width": 15, "height": 15},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "grouping",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "labelPadding": -7,
            "orient": "bottom",
            "title": null,
            "labelAngle": 0,
            "domain": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "labelLimit": 50
          },
          "sort": {"field": "d", "order": "ascending"}
        },
        "color": {
          "condition": [
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B1'", "value": "#F95F3E"},
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B2'", "value": "#308DDC"},
            {"test": "datum.d == 'B3'", "value": "#2BC121"}
          ],
          "value": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"axis": {"titleColor": "black"}, "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
}
```